# Apache .htaccess redirect URL directories containing parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry to be the asker of yet another tedious mod_rewrite question but after having made no progress in the last few hours, I thought it was time to ask ;)

I am trying to redirect URLs like these:

/some/thing?a=1 --> http://something-else.com/blah

/some/thing?a=1&b=whatever --> http://something-else.com/blah2

No need to keep the param values - the new URL will be hard-coded for each one I have to be redirected.

Have tried a few different things from other posts but with no joy so I am back to square one so any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule-set:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=1$
RewriteRule /some/thing http://something-else.com/blah [L]
```

This is indeed quite a common question, and people tend to overlook the `QUERY_STRING` variable. Have you tried it before?

Comment: Thanks. I was adding the rules at the bottom rather than directly below the "RewriteEngine On" which was preventing it from working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in the end:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(a=1&b=whatever)$

RewriteRule /some/thing http://something-else.com/blah2 [L,R=301]

I was adding the rules at the bottom rather than directly below the "RewriteEngine On" which was preventing it from working.

This solution does still append the params to http://something-else.com/blah2 which isn't exactly what I wanted but it will do.